# Unity3D Skybox Material w/ Sun or Moon and positioning directional light?

Tags: 3d, 2d, transform, unity-game-engine

How to precisely align a light source to a Sun or Moon in a skybox material?  Currently, the notion of "looking up" from a game character and playing with the transform positions until you get it right method is (well) cumbersome, tedious and sorta lame.  Any way to determine what the coordinates (transform.position) are of any object within a skybox material using another tool?

Anyone have any experience with this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [the answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29229/sun-coordination-with-skybox.html).

If you turn on the **Sky** in the **Scene View** it becomes pretty elementary aligning directional lights. With directional lights, distance doesn't matter, however, rotation is everything.